# Which prefixes are needed with animations?

Tags: css, css-animations

I asked me a question. When I create animation with the -webkit- prefix (or an another prefixes), I need to write properties with this prefix only or I must add all of the prefixes.

e.g.

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

or

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
        -o-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since only WebKit browsers can apply `@-webkit-keyframes` rules, it doesn't make any sense whatsoever to include any other prefixes inside those rules.

You want to include other prefixes for the `@keyframes` rules, not the properties within them. The properties inside use matching prefixes where appropriate:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0% { -moz-transform: scale(0); }
    100% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0% { -o-transform: scale(0); }
    100% { -o-transform: scale(1); }
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% { transform: scale(0); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

(There is no `@-ms-keyframes`, and it is not necessary to use `-ms-transform` in `@keyframes`.)

Comment: Ok, that's what I believed, but I wanted to be sure. I add the -ms- prefix, if the next version of the browser supports this property.

Comment: IE10 already supports `@keyframes` without the prefix, so there really isn't a need to add the prefix. Trust me.

Comment: Ok, so I will delete the -ms- prefix. Thanks.

Comment: You should check out prefixr.com It does all the prefixing for you. There are even a bunch of plugins out there that let you use it straight from your code editor. I use it all the time!

Comment: @PeterVR: I use -prefix-free instead. Prefixr seems to be really outdated - it still produces the old gradient syntax unprefixed which is no longer used. It also spits `@-ms-keyframes` which was only used by the IE10 Platform Previews and not the stable release.